# Multiple subclasses, how to instance any of them?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, subclass

This will be a bit hard to explain, but I will try my best.

I want to have multiple items that, when clicked, each have a different result. For the rest, they all have the same variables. So basically, I have a class Item, and subclasses Ball, Rope, Book, and many, many more to come. I want to be able to easily add items if I want to. The Item class has a String name, String description and a method 'onUse' that each of the subclasses override.

I would like to handle this as dynamical as possible, meaning I would like a single method in my Frame/Activity (This is for Android but Java applies) to execute the method.

I'm using this for a single method:

```
public void useItem(Item i)
{
    i.onUse();
}
```

My problem is that I have the different items saved in a database. I want to randomly grab one of the items from the database and instance it; except I have no way of knowing which subclass to instance it as. I tried saving the datatype in the database but that's not really working out... Pseudocode:

```
//Database cursor stuff
//...
                String itemType = c.getString(6);

                //Get the class name if possible
                Class itemClass= null;
                try {
                    itemClass = Class.forName(itemType);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException)
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Item l = null;
            // Check here what type it is!
            if (itemClass.equals(Ball.class)) {
                l = new Ball(name,description);

            } else if(lootClass.equals(Book.class)){

                l = new Book(name,description); 
            }
```

Seeing as there are so many different items this isn't really great as I would have to iterate through loads of classes (plus I often the get ClassNotFoundException)

What say you, StackOverflow? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Read up on design patterns. The Visitor Pattern might work well for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory pattern is probably the way to go.  If you store the fully qualified name in the DB then you can create a factory that reads the value and instantiates a new Item using the following:

```
Item item = (Item) Class.forName(theDBField).newInstance();
item.setName(name);
item.setDescription(desc);
```

Which means a much more concise factory that doesn't have to know about all the classes it can build.  I really dislike having to update a factory everytime I add a new implementation and this is a simple way to avoid it.

to do this you will have to add getters and setters to the item interface.

Comment: This might not be the best solution, but it was exactly the solution I was looking for in my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would use a **Factory method pattern** (aka Factory pattern).

Factory method pattern is a creational pattern. The creational patterns abstract the
object instantiation process by **hiding** how the objects are created and make the system independent of the object creation process.

Lets try to implement how it should work:

**Model**

```
public abstract class Model {  
   protected abstract void init();
}
```

**Book**

```
public class Book extends Model {
 @Override
protected void init() {
    System.out.println("I'm a Book");
}
}
```

**Ball**

```
public class Ball extends Model {
    @Override
protected void init() {
    System.out.println("I'm a Ball");
}
}
```

**DbModelFactory**

```
public abstract class DbModelFactory {
    public abstract Model getModel(int modelId);
}
```

**SimpleDbModelFactory**

```
public class SimpleDbModelFactory extends DbModelFactory  {

    @Override
    public Model getModel(int modelId) {
        Model model = null;
        if(modelId == Const.MODEL_BOOK) {

            model = new Book();
        }
        else if(modelId == Const.MODEL_BALL) {

            model = new Ball();
        }
        else {// throw Exception

        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Const**

```
public class Const {
    public static final int MODEL_BOOK = 0;
    public static final int MODEL_BALL = 1;
}
```

**Launcher**

```
public class Launcher {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DbModelFactory factory  = new SimpleDbModelFactory();
    Model book = factory.getModel(0);
    book.init(); // I'm a Book

    Model ball = factory.getModel(1);
    ball.init(); //I'm a Ball
    }
}
```

Factory pattern returns one of the several product subclasses. You should use a factory
pattern If you have a super class and a number of subclasses and based on some data provided, you have to return the object of one of the subclasses

Now we have 2 `Models` `book` and `ball` and we don't care that both are actually `Model`.

Comment: This is kind of what I've gotten to so far, but as soon as there will be more objects, I would have to keep modifying the Factory class. In my opinion, it should be easier than that.

Comment: anyways its easy way to maintain Factory class. add 3 rows to switch case.

Comment: Is this the preferred way if you have a lot of subclasses? Eg: 20,30...

Comment: @theyuv this is the main idea of Factory pattern

Comment: The if/else portion can get rather long if you have a lot of sub-classes though.

Comment: @theyuv use switch-case

Comment: This is relevant for `switch` too. The code for instantiating 30 different subclasses in a switch (with 30 cases) is rather long. I'm asking if this is still the best way to do it? It just seems like there might be a more elegant solution (my switch clause is growing each time I add a subclass)... Thanks.