# android inheritance - instantiating multiple different subclasses through a single object?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am working on a paint program for android. I want to create generic 'tools' which are sent MotionEvents as parameters and use them to perform tasks like drawing or erasing elements on a page. I want to program it so that one tool superclass can change to be any of the subclass tools. I did some browsing on SO and found a similar question here: [Multiple subclasses, how to instance any of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369723/multiple-subclasses-how-to-instance-any-of-them)

I'm not sure if it fully applies though, and the user-checked answer is a little confusing to me. If anyone could elaborate on that question's answer, or shed some more light on my goal, then I would be most appreciative.

EDIT: What I want to accomplish is to take something like the code below:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                currentTool.Touch(event);
                //drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                currentTool.Move(event); //drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                currentTool.Untouch(event);
                //drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                //drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Where `currentTool` can be changed by the user as they use the program. Whenever the user touches the screen, the posted code will run, but what tool is used can change based on what tool the user has selected (so a pencil tool will draw lines, an eraser tool will erase lines, etc.). I wanted to do this to have better OO design in my program, and to make it easier to add or remove tools later on.

Comment: You mean you want the type of an existing object to change at execution time? You can't do that. What you *can* do is have a variable of type `Tool` (the superclass) and change its value to refer to instances of different subclasses over the course of its lifetime. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve though. Sample code would really help...

Comment: apparently you have a class or an interface `Tool` that contains the methods `touch`, `move`, `untouch`, each tool subclass implementing the required behavior. Then somewhere in the listener that receives the tool selection, instanciate your tool : `currentTool = new EraserTool()`, where `EraserTool` would be the implementation of `Tool` in charge of erasing.